# difference in accessing elements via jquery object find

Tags: jquery, dom

```
<div id="target">
    <dd>
    <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    </ul>
    </dd>
    </div>
```

This html is generated dynamically.

```
var $target = $("#target");
```

I'm able to find the ul when I search like this  $("#target").find('dd ul') but not when I do $target.find('dd ul'). What's wrong with this approach? I'm just saving the same object into a variable and finding it.

Comment: The only way I could see that not working is if `$target` is assigned the value before the html is generated.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: Can you recreate this in jsFiddle? [I can't.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVu9h/)